# Android and JSON Youtube Playlist

Tags: android, json, api, youtube, playlist

Ok, I am parsing a playlist from YouTube using a GDATA link. I have decided to use JSON rather than parse XML. Can someone point me towards an intuitive tutorial for this.

Note: I have already been through the YouTube API page and I cannot get what I need from it, so save yourself the trouble :)

Also note: this playlist needs to be shown in a listview. I can do this part easily, but if you could just point me to the JSON part I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has really good libraries for parsing json. You can use [JSONObject(String json)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) constructor to create a json object for parsing from your response you got from YouTube. From there you can easily extract what you are looking for with methods such as [optString](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I didn't know this library existed THANKS!

Comment: @Derok8 Don't forget to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for.